# Only some of my assets are browser cached in Rails development environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I'm running rails 3.2.  I'm trying to get page refreshes to be as fast as possible in development mode, so I've set the following config for my assets:

```
  config.static_cache_control = "public, max-age=3600"
  config.assets.debug = false
  config.assets.digest = true
```

The idea is to have all assets served with a digest and be browser-cached.  What I'm seeing is that only some of my assets are cached properly:

```
cache: [GET /assets/homepage/post-f7a1b20c625428032e3acf51388c8a6c.png] fresh
cache: [GET /assets/general/posted_check-0cf4eac99c06719e1ddf56a091550e80.png] fresh
cache: [GET /assets/general/about_footer.png] stale, valid, store
cache: [GET /assets/general/social_footer.png] stale, valid, store
```

The last two are getting Cache-Control:no-cache back from the server and I can't figure out why.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After setting config.assets.digest = true I have to clear the Sprockets asset cache. Deleting tmp/cache/assets fixed it.